# Django forms custom field Left Outer Join

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form where I add CUSTOM FIELD checkbox miltiple. The data is simply loaded like this

```
widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            queryset = Product.objects.all (),
            required = False,
            )
```

This is a good solution when I create a new instance of the Component model. In the case of editing, however, it is a problem because some of the checkboxes can be filled. So I need to change the queryset for this field a little. I wanted to do it like

```
prod = Product.objects.annotate (dupa = FilteredRelation ('product', condition = Q (product__component = 120))). Values ​​('short_name', 'name', 'dupa__component'),
```

but it gets error  **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: missing FROM-clause entry for table" t7
LINE 1: ... a ON ("epm_product". "Id" = ass. "Product_id" AND (T7. "Comp ...".**

Query returns :

SELECT "epm_product "." Short_name "," epm_product ". "name", "epm_productitem_component". "component_id" FROM "epm_product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "epm_productitem" dupa ON ("epm_product". "id" = dupa. "product_id" AND (T5. "component_id" = 120)) LEFT OUTER JOIN "epm_productitem_component" ON (ass. "Id" = "epm_productitem_component". "Productitem_id")

To test the data and how it is presented, I used the usual SQL query:

```
"select pr.name, pr.short_name
, (select count (*) from epm_productitem pi left join epm_productitem_component pic on pic.productitem_id = pi.id
  where pic.component_id = 120 and pi.product_id = pr.id) ccheck
from epm_product pr
```

which gives me this result

| name | short name | check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Pilot small" | "PM" | 1 |
| "Receiver very small" | "BM" | 0 |
| "Receiver large" | "D" | 0 |
| "Medium receiver extended" | "SR" | 0 |
| "Medium receiver" | "S" | 0 |
| "Receiver small" | "M" | 0 |
| "Slave heat pump" | "PC slave" | 0 |
| "Heat pump controller" | "PC LCD" | 1 |

Could you please help me properly add the custom field to the form so that I can get the raw SQL output?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a solution that meets my expectations. I thought that with one queryset I would be able to create a MultipleChoice Field and immediately mark the checkboxes that result from the relationship. However, it seems that you need to use the

> inital

property and enter the values selected by default there.
Now my field definition looks like this.

```
product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField (
            widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            queryset = Product.objects.all(),
            required = False,
            initial = Product.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(product__component = 120),
            )
```

This passage also deserves attention

> .values_list('id', flat=True)

which allows you to easily pass the list.

There is still the problem of data recording, but I can handle it.

greetings